# Using the string that matches "%" in a make pattern rule

Tags: makefile

I'm using a pattern rule for a series of directories (they happen to be Django locale files, though that shouldn't make any difference). The translations directory contains four or five subfolders, each of which has exactly the same structure. I'm trying to say:

> If the file name `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` in folder
>   `translations/x` is more recent than the file
>   `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` in the same folder,
>   run some command with *x* as an argument.

Here's my attempt at expressing that as a rule. The (obvious) problem is that "%" in the recipe portion of the rule doesn't mean "whatever matched the '%' in the target".

```
translations/%/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po: translations/%/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po: 
    tx push -s -r project.% && \
    tx pull -r project.% && \
    bin/dev/manage.py compilemessages
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Correction as per accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean to say *the `%` in the recipe portion of the rule*, not the *rule portion of the statement*.

See the page on [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) which will lead you to:

> ### `$*`
>
> The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match).

So:

```
translations/%/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po: translations/%/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po: 
        tx push -s -r project.$* && \
        tx pull -r project.$* && \
        bin/dev/manage.py compilemessages
```